# How can I link a checkbox in Android to an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am creating an application where the user has a list of options as check boxes and I wanted to know is there a way to link the options to an array so that once one or more check boxs is clicked it can access what is in the array?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're trying to do? I'm unclear what "it" refers to when you say "it can access what is in the array".

Comment: Check out ListView + Adapter.